# How would I turn this forEach to a forLoop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

so I know that the colors and color are different but I don't really know how to go about changing it to a forLoop function.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

numbers.forEach(function(color){
  if(color % 3 ===0) {
    console.log(color);
  }
});
```

Comment: why do you want to change that? what is your expectation from this code?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what you want the code to do. Also a small typo: `if(color% 3 ===0` should be `if(color% 3 ===0)`.

Comment: I am currently learning javascript and my "teacher" said it would be a good idea to learn how to turn foreach into forloop (pretty sure I will learn it in later lessons but I still would like to know). I have tried a few different things but the code still will not work.

Comment: `for` is interesting from an academic perspective, but this code is textbook how you iterate over an array.

Comment: You need to add your expected output to your question because none of us understand what your code is meant to do at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: But how does this relate to `colors`?

Comment: Why was this voted down? It does the same thing as the OP's code but using a `for` loop, which is exactly what was asked for. (@Andy - the OP's code didn't use `colors` at all. Possibly the OP is trying to somehow use the `colors` array, but they don't say so.)

Comment: Clearly the OP wants to do something with `colors` and this answer doesn't cover that because _we don't know what the OP wants_.

Comment: Well - they've been given what they asked for, even though what they asked for may not be what they actually wanted. Which is probably a good lesson for them to learn about what any piece of code does, too...